# How to set up a temporary local port forwarding from a port to an other on windows?

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a server (cassini) that listens on port `XXXX`. It accepts only connections from localhost. This is not configurable.

I would like to temporarily run a program that will listen on port `YYYY` from all network interfaces, and forward each connection to port `XXXX` on localhost.

What's a good tool to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research and testing it appears that http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport was a good solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many. Quick google search revealed for Windows:

http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php

Comment: Sorry but this one is just not working in my case. I don't know why but the server closes the connection from the program. As there is a ton of utilities I was looking for an the advice of an experimented user rather than testing all of them. I finally found http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjs-passport/.